# Is there a way to see a connection between Law of Total Probability and Law of Total Expectation?

Tags: probability, expected-value

Both the Law of Total Probability and Law of Total Expectation are suspiciously similar looking:

> $$E(X) = \sum_{i} E(X|A_i)P(A_i) $$
>
> $$P(A) = \sum_{n} P(A|B_n)P(B_n) $$ where $B_n$ partitions the sample space.

Is one a special case of the other? Are they both just coincidentally true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second one is  special case of the first. Just take $X=I_A$.

Comment: Sorry could you please elaborate on how it would work?
$ X = I_A $, So we have $ E(I_A) = \sum_i E(I_A|A_i)P(A_i)$. I see that the LHS becomes $ P(A) $ but I'm not sure how the inside of the sum becomes $P(A|A_i)P(A_i) $

Comment: When $X=I_A$ we have $EX=P(A)$ and  $E(X|A_i)=\frac {P(A\cap A_i)} {P(A_i)}=P(A|A_i)$.

Answer (score 4):

The probability of an event $A$ is the expected value of the corresponding indicator random variable $1_A = \cases{1 & if $A$ occurs\cr 0 & otherwise}$.  Similarly for conditional probability and conditional expectation.